# duplicate-able inputs validation not working with non duplicate-able fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of creating a duplicate-able form, i have run into a slight problem though.

i have a main-member inputs and a duplicate-able dependent inputs that gets run through an id validation, that automatically gives you age and sex based on your id.

and my problem is, all the duplicates get unique ages and sex's based on there id but the main member gets the sex of the first dependent.

The code has to stay in the same format as it is now to work with the rest of the code.

heres a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/ZQwZm/
example of an id: 85 0929 5266086
and the code:

jQuery:

```
// JavaScript Document
//Clone Tracking
var g_counter = 1;
var d_counter = 1;
var dependant = ["dependant"];
var group;
//Clone Tracking

//Main Variables
var main_input_groups = ["main_group-1"];
var main_age_input_groups = ["main_age_group-1"];
var main_gender_input_groups = ["main_gender_group-1"];
//Main Variables
//General Variables
var input_groups = ["group-1"];
var age_input_groups = ["age-group-1"];
var gender_input_groups = ["gender-group-1"];
var idNumber;
var cell_values;
var pass_values;
var values;
//General Variables
//Generate variables
var id_fields = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13];
var age_fields=[0,1];
var gender_fields=[0];
//Main Member generate
var main_id_fields = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13];
var main_age_fields = [0,1];
var main_gender_fields = [0];
//Main Member generate
//Main Member inputs
var mainID;
var mainPAS;
var mainCon;
var mainCod;
//Main Member inputs
//Main Member gen
var main_id_input = "<input class='mainid' maxlength='1' name='mainid' type='text' />";
var main_age_input = "<input class='mainage' maxlength='1' name='mainage' type='text' />";
var main_gender_input = "<input class='maingender' maxlength='1 name='maingender' type='text' />";
//Main Member gen
var id_input = "<input class='id' maxlength='1' name='id' type='text' />";
var age_input = "<input class='age' name='age' type='text' />";
var gender_input = "<input class='gender' maxlength='1' name='gender' type='text' />";
//Generate variables
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    //Member
    jQuery(main_id_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(main_id_input).appendTo('#main_group-1');
    });
    jQuery(main_age_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(main_age_input).appendTo('#main_age_group-1');
    });
    jQuery(main_gender_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(main_gender_input).appendTo('#main_gender_group-1');
    });
    //Member
    //populate jquery generated fields
    jQuery(id_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(id_input).appendTo('#group-1');
    });
    jQuery(age_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(age_input).appendTo('#age-group-1');
    });
    jQuery(gender_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(gender_input).appendTo('#gender-group-1');
    });
    //populate jquery generated fields
    //Cloning Function
    jQuery('#clone').click(function() {
        clone_dependant();
    });

    function clone_dependant() {
        // Store the value of the previous Id to insert the cloned div..
        var oldId = g_counter;
        g_counter++;
        currentdep ='dependant-'+g_counter;
        // Clone the Dependant Div and set a new id
        var $clonedDiv = jQuery('#dependant-1').clone(false).attr('id', 'dependant-'+g_counter);
        var gender_newDiv = 'gender-group-'+ g_counter;
        var age_newDiv = 'age-group-'+ g_counter;
        var id_newDiv = 'group-'+ g_counter;

        // Find div's inside the cloned object and set a new id's
        $clonedDiv.find('#group-1').attr('id',"group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#age-group-1').attr('id',"age-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#gender-group-1').attr('id',"gender-group-" + g_counter );

        // You don't need to Loop thru the inputs to set the value
        $clonedDiv.find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $clonedDiv.find('input[type="text"]').val('');


        // Insert the cloned object 
        $clonedDiv.insertAfter("#dependant-" + oldId);
        age_input_groups.push(age_newDiv);
        gender_input_groups.push(gender_newDiv);
        input_groups.push(id_newDiv);
    }
    //Cloning Function
    //Validation
    function validate_Id(values) {
            idNumber = values;
            var correct = true;
            if (idNumber.length != 13 || !isNumber(idNumber)) {correct = false;}
            var tempDate = new Date(idNumber.substring(0, 2), idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1, idNumber.substring(4, 6));
            var today = new Date();
            var id_date = tempDate.getDate();
            var id_month = tempDate.getMonth();
            var id_year = tempDate.getFullYear();
            var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
            var age = Math.floor((today-tempDate) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var fullDate = id_date + "-" + (id_month + 1) + "-" + id_year;
            if (!((tempDate.getYear() == idNumber.substring(0, 2)) && (id_month == idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1) && (id_date == idNumber.substring(4, 6)))) {
correct = false;}
            var genderCode = idNumber.substring(6, 10);
            var gender = parseInt(genderCode) < 5000 ? "Female" : "Male";
            var citzenship = parseInt(idNumber.substring(10, 11)) == 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
            var tempTotal = 0;
            var checkSum = 0;
            var multiplier = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {tempTotal = parseInt(idNumber.charAt(i)) * multiplier;
            if (tempTotal > 9) {tempTotal = parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(0)) + parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(1));}
                checkSum = checkSum + tempTotal;
                multiplier = (multiplier % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;}
            if ((checkSum % 10) != 0) {correct = false;};
            if (correct) {
                 $.each(age_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = 'age-group-'+g_counter;
                    var agevalues = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        $('#'+id + ' input').first().val(Math.floor(age / 10));
                        $('#'+id + ' input').last().val(age % 10);
                        //return $(e).val(age);
                    });
                });
               $.each(gender_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = 'gender-group-'+g_counter;
                    var gendervalues = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val(gender);
                    });
                });

                $.each(main_gender_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = 'main_gender_group-'+g_counter;
                    var maingendervalues = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val(gender);
                    });
                });

                $.each(main_age_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = 'main_age_group-'+g_counter;
                    var mainagevalues = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        $('#'+id + ' input').first().val(Math.floor(age / 10));
                        $('#'+id + ' input').last().val(age % 10);
                    })
                });

                return idNumber;
            }
            else {
                console.log(idNumber + "-wrong");
            }
            return false;
        }

    function isNumber(n) {return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);};
    //Validation
//Multiple Inputs function
//ID
    $(document).on('keydown', 'input.id', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).prev().val('');
            $(this).prev().focus();
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', 'input.id', function() {
        if (this.value.match(/\d+/)) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.next('input.id').length) {
                $this.next().focus();
            } else {
                $.each(input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = input_groups[i];
                    values = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val();
                    }).join('');
                    validate_Id(values);
                });
            }
        }
    });
//ID
//MainID
    $(document).on('keydown', 'input.mainid', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).prev().val('');
            $(this).prev().focus();
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', 'input.mainid', function() {
        if (this.value.match(/\d+/)) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.next('input.mainid').length) {
                $this.next().focus();
            } else {
                $.each(main_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = main_input_groups[i];
                    values = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val();
                    }).join('');
                    validate_Id(values);
                });
            }
        }
    });
//MainID
//Multiple Inputs function

//Basic Validation
//Digits only
jQuery(".id").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }
});
//Digits only
$('.error').hide();

//Basic Validation
//submit function
var result = {};
var dependants;
var mainmember;
var dep_counter = 0;
jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
    jQuery('.main-member').each(function(k, v){
        mainmember  = {}
        result['mainmember'] = [mainmember];
        mainmember['id'] = ''; 
        $(v).find('.mainid').each(function(){mainmember['id'] += $(this).val();});
        mainmember['age'] = ''; 
        $(v).find('.mainage').each(function(){
          mainmember['age'] += $(this).val(); 
        });
        mainmember['gender'] = $(v).find('.main_gender').val();
    });
    jQuery('.dependant').each(function(k, v){
        var dep_id = idNumber;
        var iden_values;
        dep_counter++
        dependants = {};
        result['dependant'+dep_counter] = [dependants];
        dependants['id'] = ''; 
        $(v).find('.id').each(function(){
          dependants['id'] += $(this).val(); 
        });
        dependants['age'] = ''; 
        $(v).find('.age').each(function(){
          dependants['age'] += $(this).val(); 
        });
        dependants['gender'] = $(v).find('.gender').val();
    });
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(result);

    console.log(jsonData);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {parameters: jsonData}
    });
});
//submit function
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="app_wrap">
    <div class="main-member">
        <div class="block_wrap left border_right">
            <div class="block">main id-number:<div id="main_group-1" class="right"></div></div>
            <div class="block_half left border_right">age:<div id="main_age_group-1" class="right"></div></div>
            <div class="block_half right">gender:<div id="main_gender_group-1" class="right"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dependant-1" class="dependant">
    <div id="dependant">
        <div class="block_wrap left border_right">
            <div class="block">duplicate id-number:<div id="group-1" class="right"></div></div>
            <div class="block_half left border_right">age:<div id="age-group-1" class="right"></div></div>
            <div class="block_half right">gender: <div id="gender-group-1" class="right"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <button id="clone">Add a Dependant</button>
    <button id="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

if any further explanation is needed feel free to ask.
Thanks, any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the duplicate forms? You should enter new id's there and they are actually independent or some of the data from the main form should be filled directly?

Comment: no not at all, sorry heres an example of an id number that you would type in: 85 0929 5266086

Comment: So each form is independent and when you fill an id it should generate age and gender for its own?

Comment: and when you click submit, it stringify's all the values and gets sent..

Comment: yes exactly that, and it does.. but not the main member

Comment: There are many things which should be fixed, give me little time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how can be solved http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/ZQwZm/12/

I simplified the code a lot but you need to refactor it to became more readable.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
// JavaScript Document
//Clone Tracking
var g_counter = 1;
var d_counter = 1;
var dependant = ["dependant"];
var group;
//Clone Tracking

//Main Variables
var main_input_groups = ["group-1"];
var main_age_input_groups = ["age_group-1"];
var main_gender_input_groups = ["gender_group-1"];
//Main Variables
//General Variables
var input_groups = ["group-2"];
var age_input_groups = ["age-group-2"];
var gender_input_groups = ["gender-group-2"];
var idNumber;
var cell_values;
var pass_values;
var values;
//General Variables
//Generate variables
var id_fields = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13];
var age_fields=[0,1];
var gender_fields=[0];
//Main Member generate
var main_id_fields = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13];
var main_age_fields = [0,1];
var main_gender_fields = [0];
//Main Member generate
//Main Member inputs
var mainID;
var mainPAS;
var mainCon;
var mainCod;
//Main Member inputs
//Main Member gen
var main_id_input = "<input class='id' maxlength='1' name='id' type='text' />";
var main_age_input = "<input class='age' name='age' type='text' />";
var main_gender_input = "<input class='gender' maxlength='1' name='gender' type='text' />";
//Generate variables
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    //Member
    jQuery(main_id_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(main_id_input).appendTo('#group-1');
    });
    jQuery(main_age_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(main_age_input).appendTo('#age_group-1');
    });
    jQuery(main_gender_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(main_gender_input).appendTo('#gender_group-1');
    });
    //Member
    //populate jquery generated fields
    //Cloning Function
    jQuery('#clone').click(function() {
        clone_dependant();
    });

    function clone_dependant() {
        // Store the value of the previous Id to insert the cloned div..
        var oldId = g_counter;
        g_counter++;
        currentdep ='dependant-'+g_counter;
        // Clone the Dependant Div and set a new id
        var $clonedDiv = jQuery('#dependant-1').clone(false).attr('id', currentdep);
        var gender_newDiv = 'gender-group-'+ g_counter;
        var age_newDiv = 'age-group-'+ g_counter;
        var id_newDiv = 'group-'+ g_counter;

        // Find div's inside the cloned object and set a new id's
        $clonedDiv.find('#group-1').attr('id',"group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#age-group-1').attr('id',"age-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#gender-group-1').attr('id',"gender-group-" + g_counter );

        // You don't need to Loop thru the inputs to set the value
        $clonedDiv.find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $clonedDiv.find('input[type="text"]').val('');


        // Insert the cloned object 
        $clonedDiv.insertAfter("#dependant-" + oldId);
        age_input_groups.push(age_newDiv);
        gender_input_groups.push(gender_newDiv);
        input_groups.push(id_newDiv);
    }
    //Cloning Function
    //Validation
    function validate_Id(values, p) {
            idNumber = values;
            var correct = true;
            if (idNumber.length != 13 || !isNumber(idNumber)) {correct = false;}
            var tempDate = new Date(idNumber.substring(0, 2), idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1, idNumber.substring(4, 6));
            var today = new Date();
            var id_date = tempDate.getDate();
            var id_month = tempDate.getMonth();
            var id_year = tempDate.getFullYear();
            var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
            var age = Math.floor((today-tempDate) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var fullDate = id_date + "-" + (id_month + 1) + "-" + id_year;
            if (!((tempDate.getYear() == idNumber.substring(0, 2)) && (id_month == idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1) && (id_date == idNumber.substring(4, 6)))) {
correct = false;}
            var genderCode = idNumber.substring(6, 10);
            var gender = parseInt(genderCode) < 5000 ? "Female" : "Male";
            var citzenship = parseInt(idNumber.substring(10, 11)) == 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
            var tempTotal = 0;
            var checkSum = 0;
            var multiplier = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {tempTotal = parseInt(idNumber.charAt(i)) * multiplier;
            if (tempTotal > 9) {tempTotal = parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(0)) + parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(1));}
                checkSum = checkSum + tempTotal;
                multiplier = (multiplier % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;}
            if ((checkSum % 10) != 0) {correct = false;};
            if (correct) {
                var aig = p.find('.age');
                aig.first().val(Math.floor(age / 10));
                aig.last().val(age % 10);
                p.find('.gender').val(gender);
                /*
                $.each(main_gender_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = 'main_gender_group-'+g_counter;
                    var maingendervalues = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val(gender);
                    });
                });

                $.each(main_age_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = 'main_age_group-'+g_counter;
                    var mainagevalues = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        $('#'+id + ' input').first().val(Math.floor(age / 10));
                        $('#'+id + ' input').last().val(age % 10);
                    })
                });*/

                return idNumber;
            }
            else {
                console.log(idNumber + "-wrong");
            }
            return false;
        }
        clone_dependant();
    function isNumber(n) {return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);};
    //Validation
//Multiple Inputs function
//ID
    $(document).on('keydown', 'input.id', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).prev().val('');
            $(this).prev().focus();
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', 'input.id', function() {
        if (this.value.match(/\d+/)) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.next('input.id').length) {
                $this.next().focus();
            } else {
                var input_groups = $this.parent();
                console.log(input_groups);
                $.each(input_groups , function(i){
                    var inpg = input_groups[i];
                    values = $.map($(inpg).children('input'), function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val();
                    }).join('');
                    validate_Id(values, input_groups.parent().parent());
                });
            }
        }
    });
//ID
//MainID
    $(document).on('keydown', 'input.id', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).prev().val('');
            $(this).prev().focus();
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', 'input.id', function() {
        if (this.value.match(/\d+/)) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.next('input.id').length) {
                $this.next().focus();
            } else {
                var main_input_groups = $this.parent();
                $.each(main_input_groups , function(i, el){
                    values = $.map($(el).children('input'), function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val();
                    }).join('');
                    validate_Id(values, main_input_groups.parent().parent().parent());
                });
            }
        }
    });
//MainID
//Multiple Inputs function

//Basic Validation
//Digits only
jQuery(".id").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }
});
//Digits only
$('.error').hide();

//Basic Validation
//submit function
var result = {};
var dependants;
var mainmember;
var dep_counter = 0;
jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
    jQuery('div[class*="dependant"]').each(function(k, v){
        var dep_id = idNumber;
        var iden_values;
        dep_counter++
        dependants = {};
        result['dependant'+k] = [dependants];
        dependants['id'] = ''; 
        $(v).find('.id').each(function(){
          dependants['id'] += $(this).val(); 
        });
        dependants['age'] = ''; 
        $(v).find('.age').each(function(){
          dependants['age'] += $(this).val(); 
        });
        dependants['gender'] = $(v).find('.gender').val();
    });
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(result);

    console.log(jsonData);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {parameters: jsonData}
    });
});
//submit function
});
```

Comment: You are amazing.. i wanna have your babies!!(not really just joking).. thank you so much.. hey cant i study under you in some way??? :D

Comment: You have helped me so much already that i actually feel bad for asking, but i I've been trying for the past hour to correct my code like you did, but it just keeps freaking out on me, here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/BV5yN/ of all the code, if you can help me it would be fantastic, otherwise don't stress ill find a way :) thank you so much again... btw the only slight problem in ur correction is the JSON output, which currently is: {"dependant0":[{"id":"8911060018082","age":"23","gender":"Female"}],"dependant1":[{"id":"9306045265081","age":"19","gender":"Male"}]}

Comment: when it should be: {"mainmember":[{"id":"8911060018082","age":"23","gender":"Female"}],"dependant1"‌​:[{"id":"9306045265081","age":"19","gender":"Male"}]}

Comment: Hahah, you can find me in the social networks listed at my profile (I'm most active at twitter). Best regards :-)

Comment: hey, if you get time, i have run into what i hope is the last possible difficulty on this form - http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14442058/duplicatable-inputs-validation

Comment: I saw the question...So much source code I don't have that much spare time. I'm sorry.